# Where to put the sdk file

Tags: android, sdk, components, manual

I have downloaded the android studio and I have downloaded its m2_reporsitry_r47.zip manually. But my question is that in which file or folder I have to put the sdk component so the Android studio can install it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can put the folder to any drive. You should put it to C: drive and then point the environment variables to that folder
Hope this helps.